# Como actualizo mi lista al eliminar un elemento de la lista

Tags: flutter, dart

Estoy intentando hacer un crud en flutter con una base de datos en MYSQL y llevo gran parte de este de la interfaz y funcionalidad hecha lo único que me falta hacer hacer es  que se actaulize la lista cada vez que se ejecute una acción ya sea agregar, editar o eliminar en este caso va ser la acción de eliminar. La unica manera en que se actualiza la lista es si cambio de pantalla  y regreso cada vez despues de realizar una accion para que se actualice.

```
class UserAddress extends StatefulWidget {
  final int userId;
  UserAddress({Key key, this.userId}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _UserAddressState createState() => _UserAddressState();
}

class _UserAddressState extends State<UserAddress> {
  Future<List<Address>> userAddress;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    userAddress = fetchAddressData();
  }
  Future<List<Address>> fetchAddressData() async {
    List<Address> address = await fetchAddress(http.Client(),widget.userId);
    return address;
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: SizedBox(
                  child: addressListView(userAddress)
              ),),],),),);}}
```

```
Widget addressListView(userAddress){
  return FutureBuilder<List<Address>>(
      future:userAddress,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);
        return snapshot.hasData
          ? AddressList(address: snapshot.data,)
          : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      },
  );
}
```

```
class AddressList extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Address> address;
  final Address addressData;
  AddressList({Key key, this.address, this.addressData,}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _AddressListState createState() => _AddressListState();
}

class _AddressListState extends State<AddressList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: widget.address.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return Container(
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
             TextData(data: '${widget.address[index].calle}', fontWeight: FontWeight.w400, fontSize: 17,),
            IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.delete), onPressed: ()=>deleteAddress (widget.address[index].idDireccion)),
          ],
        )
      );},);}}
```

```
Future deleteAddress(addressId) async{
  await http.post(
    serverUrl,
    headers: <String, String>{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    },
    body: jsonEncode(<String,String>{
      'idDireccion': addressId.toString(),
      'opcion': 'eliminar'
    }),
  );
}
```

Comment: sería bueno si agregas el método `deleteAddress`

Comment: ya agregue el metodo